# Qt 4.8.2. Как собрать исполняемый файл

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Создал проект Desctop-калькулятор, написал код, ошибок при компиляции не выдает, из qtcreator запускается, работает нормально. Когда запускаю файл из build каталога, говорит, что не хватает каких-то dll  Хочу сделать исполняемый exe, как его правильно собрать? Как запустить проект в режиме выпуска? Qt creator 2.6.2

Comment: так как у Вас Qt 4.8, то в большинстве случаев просто скопируйте нехватающих dll. И будет готово.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, помогло. А я уж думал, что понадобится в Qt tree разбираться

Answer (score 4):

Если хотите открыть на компьютере, где нет установленного Qt используйте
[windows-deployment](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите какие библиотеки просит, находите их в директории установки Qt, копируете в директорию с программой.