# Не запускается exe вне qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю в qt creator, все запускается. При попытке запустить exe вне creator ничего не происходит.
Все dll есть, использую msvc2017, qt5.12.6
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Поставьте метку Win, и в любом случае что-то да происходит. Ручками запустите а не кликом

Comment: Не подскажите, что за метка Win?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944069/qt-4-8-2-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/944095#944095

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, когда запускается приложение из QtCreator, то используется окружение среды, отличное от вашей рабочей среды. Т.е. здесь могут быть указаны дополнительные пути к библиотекам Qt. Например у меня в QtCreator в свойствах сборки дополнительно прописана переменная QTDIR = "C:\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_32" (у вас должно быть что-то похожее с msvc2017).

Решение может быть следующим:

1. Добавить данную переменную в переменные среды.
2. Добавить путь
   "C:\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_32\bin" к переменной среды Path (обратите
   внимание, что добавил подкатолог bin).
3. Использовать статическую
   сборку приложений (тогда никакие dll вообще не нужны).
4. Использовать
   утилиту windeployqt.

Сам использую последний метод.

**Комментарии по поводу использования того или другого метода.**

Вообще запуск приложения вне среды разработки подразумевает, что Вы уже добрались до распространения приложения, иначе почему бы и не запускать его далее из среды разработки. А раз так, то Вам нужно правильно подготовить приложение для переноса на другой компьютер (фактически Вы делаете приложение независимым от того стоит на компьютере Qt или нет). Первые 2 метода не годятся, поскольку так или иначе подразумевают, что на Вашем компьютере должен быть установлен Qt, а это достаточно большой объем для быстрой установки на произвольном компьютере.

Третий метод (создание статического приложения) подразумевает достаточно большой объем подготовительной работы: Вы должны пересобрать все библиотеки  Qt в статике. В результате будет собираться приложение с большим размером. Проблема еще и  заключается в том, что если у Вас набор утилит, то все утилиты будут примерно одинакового размера и размер программного пакета будет расти примерно линейно от количества утилит в пакете. (При динамической сборке такого не происходит, поскольку основной размер приложения остается в динамических библиотеках и они равноправно используются всеми утилитами).

Наконец,последний метод (windeployqt). Данная утилита собирает все необходимые библиотеки в один каталог и уже из этого каталога Вы можете запускать свое приложение. Читайте описание данной утилиты. Я же ее использую прямо при сборке проекта: использую QBS и вызов вот такой функции:

```
function WinDeployQt(input, resultPath){
    var winDeploy = new Process();
    var winDeployPath = Environment.getEnv("QTDIR")+"/bin/windeployqt";
    var qmlDir = Environment.getEnv("QTDIR")+"/qml";
    winDeployPath = winDeployPath.replace(/\\/g,"/");
    writeLog("WinDeployQt: "+ input.filePath);
    writeLog("resultPath: "+ resultPath);
    ExCode = winDeploy.exec(winDeployPath,
                            ["--release",
                             "--no-translations",
                             "--no-system-d3d-compiler",
                             "--compiler-runtime",
                             "--no-opengl-sw",
                             "--qmldir", qmlDir,
                             "--dir", resultPath,
                             input.filePath]);
    if (ExCode){
        writeLog("Error: "+winDeploy.readStdErr());
    }
    File.copy(input.filePath, resultPath+"/"+input.fileName);
}
```