# QT:как сделать чтоб в папке з exe были необходимые dll библиотеки

Tags: qt, qmake

Собственно вопрос в шапке. Что нужно прописать в qmake ,чтоб c исполняемым файлом были все dll библиотеки.

Comment: посмотрите вот тут https://evileg.com/ru/post/163/

Comment: А можно сделать с qmake?

Comment: возможно это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944095/301472

Comment: Сделал по первой ссылке, не видит SFML. Я ручками скопировал ,но видимо не все ,так как ругается на entry point